# Complex array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to create this structure in ruby

```
   {
    "list": {
       "ownerList" : [ {
                "owner" : "Nacho", 
                "list" : "MyList"
            },
            {
                "owner" : "Nacho2",
                "list" : "MyList2"
            }
         ]        
      }
   }
```

but I'm not sure how to create a multientry array in ruby. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_hash = {
  owner_list: [
    {
      owner: "Nacho",
      list: "MyList"
    },
    {
      owner: "Nacho",
      list: "MyList"
    },
  ]
}
```

This creates a hash with the data you want. You can then very easily transform it to a json if you like and make operations over it.

Comment: Could also include a root-level `{ list: { ... } }` element.